# ¿Como puedo poner el android.support libraries?

Tags: android-studio

Comenze un proyecto y por accidente no puse el android.support libraries ¿alguien sabe como puedo ponerlo sin empezar devuelta el proyecto?

Comment: Cual de todas las support libraries necesitas usar? actualmente debes usar AndroidX

Comment: Quiero usar la default, la que te deja poner cuando creas un proyecto